# AWS ELB 400 BAD_REQUEST with space at the end of a URI

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, amazon-elb

We're using AWS ELB for HTTP/S load balancing, and we've run into a pretty crazy issue with the ELB.

```
$ curl -i "http://yourdomain.com/ "
HTTP/1.1 400 BAD_REQUEST
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Close
```

It appears that the AWS ELB is doing some manner of `split(' ', $first_line)[2]` looking for HTTP/1.x version. It's understandable that this request isn't technically correct. There should be a single space between the URI and the HTTP/1.x version. But really? Unlike every other HTTP daemon on the internet, this simple request fails with AWS ELB.

Is this actually true? Can anyone else replicate this issue?

Comment: I have the same issue with space anywhere in the URL.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit old, but hopefully the answer may help other persons. I'm facing the same problem with some embedded devices doing GET requests to some web servers behind and ELB proxy (I cannot change the code doing the HTTP requests).

The ELB proxy is handling this properly (and you are getting the right answer: 400 Bad request). The spaces should be URL-encoded. Some web servers and proxies are tolerant to those spaces (Apache and Squid, at least recent versions, are examples) but whatever software is running in the the AWS ELB is not.

My workaround was to configure the load balancer to do TCP Passthrough for port 80 (listen to port 80, send to instance port 80) so that the request be processed directly by the Apache server in the EC2 instances behind the load balancer. (There is no instance stickiness with this configuration, but for my application that is not required). As mentioned, Apache seems to be Ok with that extra space at the end of the URL.